# What if I want to Retrive an Custom app - what meta data type I should use

Tags: metadata-api

I made a custom app and I want to retrieve its metadata? How shall I do

Answer (score 2):

The [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) documentation is helpful in situations like these.

In this case, the metadata name is pretty much what you would expect, "CustomApplication".

This also leads you to the [documentation on CustomApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm), which tells you the information you can expect to get back.

Usually, it is better for answers to quote the relevant parts of a link so that the information can still be found (here) if the links go dead, but in this case there's just too much information to quote.

The real value of this answer is in telling you that there is an official source of documentation.